# How to clear Kendo grid rows without invoking databound method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid with databound method which shows the message 'No Data Found for the search' in case no data gets retrieved after performing search. Now i have added a radio buttons which when clicked needs to clear the old data from the grid. The issue is i am using the code `$(grid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([]);` which does clear the grid but it also shows 'No Data Found for the search' message. Since user didn't perform any search but only changed the radio button it doesn't seem right to display that message in the grid. So, i was wondering if there was a way to clear the grid without invoking the databound method.

**Grid code that calls databound function:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SearchModel>()
             .Events(events => events.DataBound("gridDataBound"))
```

**Databound code:**

```
function gridDataBound(e) {
    var grid = e.sender;
    var gridName = "#" + grid.table.context.id;

    if (grid.dataSource.total() == 0) {
            var colCount = grid.columns.length;
            $(e.sender.wrapper)
                .find('tbody')
                .append('<tr class="kendo-data-row"><td colspan="' + colCount + '" class="no-data">No Records Meet Your Search Criteria.</td></tr>');
        }
        $(gridName).find(".k-pager-wrap").hide();
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting autoBind to false?

Comment: @whipdancer i won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way of doing this without putting an `e.preventDefault()` in the `dataBound` function. What you can do is maybe make a boolean that your dataBound function uses to check whether it should display the message or not?

Comment: what do you mean by passing boolean value?

Comment: when the user changes the radio button you'll have a function that changes a boolean let's call it `showMessage` to false. In your `dataBound` function wrap everything in a `if (showMessage)` and at the end of the `dataBound` set it back to true